# AnkerMake M5 Z-axis homing fail

Tags: homing

I recently had a big mess in my printer head in my AnkerMake M5 and had to replace the entire print head. When I replaced it, I went to test the axes to make sure they were still aligned, but now I'm getting a Z-axis homing error. I've noticed that while homing, it moves down, up, then down again, but the second time it goes down, only one side goes down (the left side). I'm not sure what to do about it and Anker's help pages aren't seeming to help me either.

I have a [video](https://i.imgur.com/ymC2TxB.mp4) showing the behavior.

I'm not quite sure how to diagnose this, any tips?

Answer (score 1):

AnkerMake seems to be aware of this problem. Their support website has a section dedicated to [correcting homing failures here](https://support.ankermake.com/s/article/How-to-fix-homing-fail).

Besides this, you'll want to make sure you didn't accidentally unplug or tug on other cables while replacing the printer head. Make sure *all* of the connections are snug, and the pins are pushed in all the way. Also make sure that the Z-axis lead screws aren't bent or sideways, as this can cause binding which could be stopping your right side from lowering properly.

Comment: I've spent plenty of time with this article today and honestly it was totally unhelpful. By lead screws, do you mean the big rods that go up either side? As far as I can tell, those are straight, but I can't actually tell. If you mean something else, I would appreciate further clarification. Their documentation just had me disassemble a bunch of stuff and put it back together but it doesn't clarify what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: When you're looking at the Lead screws, you want to make sure that they're as parallel to the *profile*, or frame, as possible. When the lead screws aren't parallel, it causes extra friction which can cause issues.

While disassembling, you want to look at the lead screws, as well as the wires, and where the plug into the main board as well as the motors. you want to make sure that they're pressed all the way into their plastic connectors, and look at the connections themselves. There's tiny metal pins inside the plastic connectors that can be pushed out on accident. Make sure those are snug

Comment: As far as I can tell, the screws are fine. Allegedly, there's a beta firmware update that fixes this. I've got a support ticket in with Anker right now, but someone on reddit mentioned that this firmware fixed it for them.